# VSCode Write a Script To Run Multiple Lines for React Native Project

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, scripting

I made a white-label application and time to time I configure it with OTA updates using Expo in React Native. The problem is that my project grows larger with more applications in it every day, and updating it all becomes more difficult. I wanted to write a script (I assume it should be bash?) to run all my updates.

Usually I update my applications like this:

```
expo publish --config app1.json --release-channel app1
```

then I run an update on the second app:

```
expo publish --config app2.json --release-channel app2
```

and so on...

How to write a single file that would run multiple lines like this in order? Any suggestion or example would be appreciated.

BTW: `expo publish` command is what runs the OTA update, so it takes some time. I don't know if script can await until command to finish or do they run in parallel? But, this is another question I suppose...

Comment: if your Linux, a bash script maybe  (.sh) with chmod +x, if your Windows a batch file.. (.bat).  ps: Both will wait unless told not too.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple script (.sh) with the help of `ShellCheck` in vscode:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting update"
param=$1

if [ "$param" = "prod" ]
then
    echo "you publish to prod now, good luck"
    expo publish --config app1.json --release-channel app1-prod
    expo publish --config app2.json --release-channel app2-prod
    #etc
elif [ "$param" = "staging" ]
then
    echo "you now publish to staging"
    expo publish --config app1.json --release-channel app1-staging
    expo publish --config app2.json --release-channel app2-staging
    #etc
else
    echo "idiot, check parameter"
fi

echo "Finished update"
```

and then I just run `./<myScript>.sh staging` or `./<myScript>.sh prod` to update all my apps at once.

I am sure there is a cleaner way to write this script without using `if/else` switch, but at this moment I`m lacking the knowledge of shell scripting :)

hope it helps for somebody.